# Configure a second x-axis with matplotlib in logscale

Tags: python, matplotlib, x-axis

I am trying to do a plot with a second x-axis on matplotlib but with a logarithmic scale.

I managed to add a second x-axis on a plot with a linear scale using the example below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_axis =  np.linspace(0,100, 100)
yvalues = x_axis**3

new_tick_locations =  np.array([20,40,60,80,100])
second_x_axis = new_tick_locations**2

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.plot(x_axis,  yvalues)
ax1.axvline(x = 60, color = 'black', linestyle = 'dotted')
ax1.set_xlabel("first x axis")
ax1.set_ylabel("yvalues")
SecondAxis = True
if(SecondAxis):
    ax2 = ax1.twiny()
    ax2.set_xlim(ax1.get_xlim())
    ax2.set_xticks(new_tick_locations )
    ax2.set_xticklabels(second_x_axis)
    ax2.set_xlabel("second x axis")
Logscale = False
if(Logscale):
    ax1.set_xscale("log")
    ax1.set_yscale("log")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Here, my second x-axis is defined as the square of my x-axis and we retrieve on the plot that for x =60 we have second_x =3600.

However, if I now set the "Logscale" variable in my code to "True" I get the following result:

[image]

Where the values of my second x-axis do not match the ones of my first x-axis.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20396236/matplotlib-how-to-set-ticks-of-twinned-axis-in-log-plot perhaps?

Comment: I think that the first answer of the post you mention @BigBen could work but I struggle to implement it in a general case like mine.